# HTML/CSS PayPal Button

Tags: html, css, paypal

I've searched quite a bit, but all results reference using a custom image. I'm working with fluid layouts/retina displays and I'd like the button to be purely HTML/CSS.

Does anyone know a workaround/method?

Comment: I'm currently using the custom image method. screenshot here:
http://cl.ly/image/3R3h2x361W3c

PayPal forces the use of <input type="image"> and I'd rather create the button using <input type="button">, for example. then I wont have to deal with twice large images for retina display. Not to mention much more control with layout changes & media queries.

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague, but if I understand correctly I think you want a button that links to your paypal. Paypal has plenty of premade buttons that are good because they have their branding. [https://www.paypal.com/newlogobuttons][1] [1]: https://www.paypal.com/newlogobuttons If you want a custom one, what you need to do is get the code for one of the above buttons, find the functional code, and apply it to one of your custom buttons. Good Luck<br />
-Brian

Comment: Brian, Thanks for the reply. Paypal offers default buttons and a custom image method. The latter is the most custom you can get and the one I'm using.

I'm looking to create the button with HTML/CSS. I'd like it to be more custom than the current PayPal options.

Comment: jpann, be careful creating your own paypal branding. Users tend to enjoy the fact that they recognize the logo, and convert higher

Comment: jpann, you can host the button at Paypal and then use its id to create custom buttons. See if this tutorial helps:- http://www.paysketch.com/create-custom-paypal-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code, I'd say hide the image with jQuery, then again use jQuery to create a new element with whatever content you want inside what I presume is the anchor tag used.

If javascript isn't supported, it'll show the image, if not, it'll show your new element (which you can style accordingly)

edit: ok, some clarification... use jquery to hide the existing input type="image"... then use jquery again to create a new input of type submit, do whatever you need it to do

Here's a fiddle to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/erinfreeman/PFZY8/

If there's a better way of doing it, I'm all ears. As below, I don't think jpann can add any additional code else it would simply be a case of hiding the existing input field and adding another.

Comment: js to hide anelement? Is that not a bit overkill. Should be easy with plain css...

Comment: I was thinking CSS too. Absolute positioning, visibility, z-index.

Comment: See jpann's comment, he's being forced to use input type image. I'd imagine the code can't be edited too much, so at a push I thought the best workaround is javascript to hide it and also javascript to recreate the button as a submit button that can be styled.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I was working on a project and the client wanted custom paypal buttons. I found a great site that provided custom code for the button: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-paypal-button-without-images/

You simply replace the input type="image" tag with an input type="submit" and style it. Hope this helps.